# Как закрасить область пересечения 4 сфер в matlab?

Tags: matlab

Доброго времени суток, господа форумчане!!!

Суть задачи такова, имеются четыре пересекающиеся сферы и нужно закрасить область их пересечения. Над задачей уже сижу несколько дней, но продвинуться так и не получилось. Вопрос стоит в том, как найти координаты пересечения этих сфер.
[image: вид сверху][image: вид сбоку]

Заранее спасибо всем!!!

Comment: Какие шаги Вы предпринимали за эти дни?

Comment: пыьтался разобраться и применить данное решение, чтобы найти общие точки https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101396-is-there-a-function-in-matlab-for-detecting-points-inside-a-polyhedron